# Hide Empty and Null Rows

Tags: excel, vba, null

I found/edited existing VBA code to create a macro that hides empty rows. It worked perfectly, until I had to edit the spreadsheet so that at least one cell in each row has a formula. Most of these formulas do not return anything, but since they do not technically equal 0 my existing macro does not hide the rows. How can I edit the below macro to hid both empty rows AND those that only have null values? Thanks!

```
    Sub HideEmpties()
        Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
        nFirstRow = r.Row
        For n = nFirstRow To nLastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(n)) = 0 Then
        Rows(n).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
       Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: If the formulas return `""` then wouldn't the count still work? What do the formulas return?

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on your code:

```
Sub HideEmpties()
        Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
        nFirstRow = r.Row

        For n = nFirstRow To nLastRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Rows(n)) = Columns.Count Then
                Rows(n).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Because *COUNTBLANK()* treats nulls like blanks.

Answer (score -1):

You might try changing `0` to `1`.